# Result data from multiple table codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Model:

```
public function show_data_by_tid_pic($postid,$postpic) {
$condtid = "otslm.tid =" . "'" . $postid . "'";
$condpic = "pic.nama =" . "'" . $postpic . "'";
$this->db->select('otslm.*');
$this->db->select('pic.*');
$this->db->from('otslm');
$this->db->join('pic', 'pic.id = otslm.id');
$this->db->where($condtid);
$this->db->where($condpic);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result(); } else {
return false;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public function inputslm() {
    $postid = $this->input->post('nametid');
    $postpic = $this->input->post('namepic');
    if ($postid != "" OR $postpic != "") {
    $resultid = $this->skejuler_model->show_data_by_tid_pic($postid,$postpic);
    if ($resultid != false) {
    $data['result_display'] = $resultid;
    }
    else {
    $data['result_display'] = "Not Found!";
    }
    }
    else {
    $data = array(
    'tid_error_message' => "TID tidak boleh kosong!",
    'pic_error_message' => "PIC tidak boleh kosong!"
    );
    }
    $data['show_table'] = $this->view_table();
    $this->load->view('front/dashboard', $data);
    }
```

View:

```
if (isset($result_display)) {
            if ($result_display == 'Not Found!') {
            echo $result_display;
            } else {
                foreach ($result_display as $vid) {
                $zlokasi = $vid->lokasi;
            $znama = $vid->nama;
            $znohp = $vid->nohp;
                }
      echo $zlokasi;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $znama;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $znohp;
            }
            }
```

After submit:

[image]

I am new to Codeigniter, trying to result data by joining table with 2 fields "nametid" and "namepic". I think the code nothing wrong, existed columns, but it always turn false (Not found!). Please help figuring this out... Thank you so much...

Using HeidiSQL (Found rows: 0), Join table Failed with where clause.
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGsYj.jpg)

Using HeidiSQL (Found rows: 31), Join table Success without where clause.
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIV1q.jpg)

Comment: The code worked with only 1 filed "nametid" then I added a new input filed "namepic" by joining the table "otslm" and "pic" but the result goes false.

Comment: after `$query = $this->db->get();` try to output your select statement with `echo $this->db->last_query();` you should be able to see the full generated statement - (pS. you should use the where function in a proper manner because right now you are fully open for sql injections - try it like `$this->where('otslm.tid', $postid);`

Comment: @sintakonte Thank you for the replay and suggestion, and done: echo $this->db->last_query();  but produces nothing, and also changed the where function as you suggested and the result still not found. Thanks again.

Comment: @sintakonte My bad, I use template with fixed top so that I can't see the output, here is the output:
SELECT *
FROM `otslm`
JOIN `pic` ON `pic`.`id` = `otslm`.`id`
WHERE `otslm`.`tid` = '550250'
AND `pic`.`nama` = 'WAWAN'

Comment: looks good isn't it ? - i don't know your table structure but based on that information you should be able to handle your problem right ?

Comment: Thanks @sintakonte for another replay, I don't have idea as I am new in CI and code, but I just added 2 pictures about executing the query via HeidiSQL.. Please have a look the edited question. Thanks again..

Comment: this is pretty simple - there is no result with `tid` `550250` AND `name` `WAWAN`

Comment: @sintakonte Yeah, but those values exist in tables. I changed the code by replacing JOIN and using multiple select instead. And it works! But still do not understand and curious why cannot use Join. Thanks.

Comment: those values may exists - but in this combination they don't...

Comment: Using join:
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('otslm');
$this->db->join('pic','pic.id = otslm.id');
$this->db->where('otslm.tid', $postid);
$this->db->where('pic.nama', $postpic);

Can you show me the correct syntax if above query is wrong..

I am now using multiple select and working. But will use Join if found the correct query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data now success without using JOIN, replaced the query with:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('otslm');
$this->db->from('pic');
$this->db->where('tid', $postid);
$this->db->where('nama', $postpic);
```